# Laravel Injecting a class into another class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to separate functionalities into two classes and I want to Inject one class into another. However, it seems that Laravel can't recognize the second class and it is always null.

```
namespace App\Services;


use App\Models\Image;
use App\Models\Offer;
    class ImagesService {
    
        public function __construct() {
        }
    
        function saveImages(iterable $images, Offer $offer): array {
           // ... code here ! 
        }
    }
```

And the class to inject in is:

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Action;
use App\Models\Offer;
use App\Models\OfferOption;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class OffersService {

    protected $imagesService;

    function __constructor(ImagesService $imgService) {
        $this->imagesService = $imgService; //Doesn't work ! $imagesService is always null! 
    }

    function doSomething() {
        $this->imagesService->saveImages(....) // Call to a member function saveImages() on null at
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I not sure but quite certain that [binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding) is what you are looking for

Comment: @NicoHaase as far I understand laravel should look at the ImageService service class and see that OfferService needs it in the constructor and inject it and this process is an automatic one.

Comment: "it seems that Laravel can't recognize the second class and it is always null" There is no magic of any kind. You have to instruct framework to use one class as dependency for another class. [This](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) is the page you are looking for.

Comment: I would think the function name is `__construct` and not `__constructor` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @Tpojka the DI container would take care of this, and usually, there's no need to configure anything, see "Zero Configuration Resolution" on the page you've linked to

Comment: @NicoHaase I see now, when concrete class is used instead of interface, no need for binding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to access and use properties from one class to another class.

1. Create an instance of the class you want to use in the class you want to use.
2. Use the class you want to use as Trait and call it use in the other class.
3. Extend the class you want to use to the class you want to use.

Comment: Sorry, I think your answer will be downgraded, I am asking about Injecting, others are not an option. I know I can do that but what I am looking for is Dependency Injection.